# Creating a co-occurrence table from a log in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a usage log in a pandas data frame:

```
event_time   session_id      object
10:00:03      1             A
10:00:03      1             B
10:00:03      1             C
10:00:03      1             E
10:00:03      2             J
10:00:03      2             O
10:00:03      2             A
10:00:03      2             A
```

I have grouped the objects by session_id. I now want to build a co-occurrence matrix of objects against objects with each cell for any given pair of objects containing the number of times those objects co-occur in a group (i.e. against the same session_id): Something along the following lines:

```
   A    B      C   ...
A  20   1     12
B  1   100     9
C  12   9     30
...
```

Is there a way to have the above in dict form so all non-zero occurrences are not represented for any given object 'key'?

Clearly the matrix will be triangular. Is there a way to pivot the matrix into a molten data table of the form:

```
Object 1   Object 2    # of co-occurences
  A           A                20
  A           B                1
 ...         ...              ...
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: I am running the algos for prototyping on 12MB of data, but will run 'for real' on AMAZON on c. 2-3 GB of data from a multi-TB data set. I dont think GB is quite Pig territory - the more efficient the suggested the answer the better

I want to to be able to look up objects in the dictionary and then see all of the objects that co-occur with them and the counts (may end up indexing this structure in Solr in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table('event_time', 'session_id', 'object',
                         aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[11]: 
object      A  B  C  E  J  O
session_id                  
1           1  1  1  1  0  0
2           2  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: This seems like something I could use to build a co-occurence table by looking at the columns. My fear is that with large data sets the 0 will become memory prohibitive (since matrix will be sparse).

Comment: Not sure how you can do this using SparseDataFrame (neither solution here is sparse), perhaps having this as a MultiIndex may be more space efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Your input

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
  event_time  session_id object
0   10:00:03           1      A
1   10:00:03           1      B
2   10:00:03           1      C
3   10:00:03           1      E
4   10:00:03           2      J
5   10:00:03           2      O
6   10:00:03           2      A
7   10:00:03           2      A

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

This is the session_id counts matrix. Get's you most of the way there. (You can of course fill then nas if you want)

```
In [81]: df.groupby('session_id').apply(lambda x: x['object'].value_counts()).unstack()
Out[81]: 
            A   B   C   E   J   O
session_id                       
1           1   1   1   1 NaN NaN
2           2 NaN NaN NaN   1   1

[2 rows x 6 columns]
```